# How to create dynamic charts using lavacharts and laravel?

Tags: charts, laravel-5

Actually i want add dynamic charts in my laravel web-application
that reacts to changes in database..I am using lavacharts..I am able to create charts that work on data that i input through my code.

here is my controller

```
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Http\Requests;
   use DB;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Khill\Lavacharts\Laravel\LavachartsFacade as Lava;

   class ratingscontroller extends Controller{

   public function index(){


      $stocktable = \Lava::DataTable();

      $stocktable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
           ->addNumberColumn('projected')
           ->addNumberColumn('official');


           for($a = 1; $a < 30; $a++){
            $stocktable->addRow([
                '2015-10-' . $a, rand(800,1000), rand(800,1000)


                ]);


           }

              $chart = \Lava::AreaChart('MyStocks', $stocktable);
                           return view('welcome');

          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see thsi is a pretty old question but if there is still need for this here goes...

From what I see here you would need three things from your database; `day_of_month`, `projected_value` and `official_value`.

Lets say you have a table in the database that maps to an eloquent model `Report`.

You can now create your `DataTable` object as follows:

```
$stocktable = \Lava::DataTable();

$stocktable->addDateColumn('Day of Month')
           ->addNumberColumn('projected')
           ->addNumberColumn('official');
//$reports should be validated with number of days in month (ex. Feb has 28 days so you would have empty days and Jan has 31 so info for one day would be missing)
//for simplicities sake i won't do this here...
$reports = Report::whereBetween('day_of_month',[1,30])->get();

for($a = 1; $a < 30; $a++){
    //I'm assuming here you only have one entry in your database per day of the month, if not you need to take this into account
    $day = $reports->where('day_of_month')->first();
    if($day){
        $stocktable->addRow([
            '2015-10-' . $a, 
            $day->projected_value, 
            $day->official_value 
        ]);
    }

\Lava::AreaChart('MyStocks', $stocktable);

}
```

With this your graph is filled with data in your database.

Hope this helps